# The Rime of the Final Girl

Tags: riddle, music

This is the second puzzle I have written, and am looking for the title of a song...

> While sleeping I heard a knock upon my cabin door;
>
> I sat up, gripped by fear at once,
>   My body turned to stone,
>   I reached for you - forgetting that
>   I was sleeping alone.
>
> I though on what I should do,
>   As I had 'ere the nights before,
>   I steeled myself and shuddered as
>   I heard the knock once more.
>
> Could it be you? I wondered,
>   We parted with such pain- 
>   You left me for distant lands,
>   Could you be here again?
>
> The door handle rattled,
>   I darted for the lock,
>   As the handle turned
>   I froze in shock!
>
> Perhaps I should have double checked
>   The bolt, the lock, the keys - 
>   A shadowy figure burst in
>   And lurched, limping, towards me.
>
> It took a swing and I ducked towards the bed,
>   I thought about crawling beneath it, lying still, playing dead,
>   But I am the Final Girl and I will be here for decades long,
>   I leave you this poem that you may guess my favourite song.

Comment: Reminiscent of Poe's "The Raven".

Comment: @msh210 that's the tone I was going for so it sounded spooky, but it's a red herring - the answer has nothing to do with 'The Raven' or Poe in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like:

> I Will Survive by Gloria Gaynor

I sat up, gripped by fear at once,

My body turned to stone

> At first I was afraid,
> I was petrified

Comment: Yes! I knew it sounded familiar! And now it’s stuck in my head....

Comment: Yeah, it's stuck in mine too now. I do like @Tonks' version though.

Comment: @ItsPete you got it! The rest of it does sort-of follow the song but probably could have been better, I'm glad you enjoyed it though.